# Five-form flux in Giddings-Kachru-Polchinski (GKP)

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, gauge-theory, compactification

I'm studying the work of [Giddings-Kachru-Polchinski (GKP)](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0105097) for hierarchies in string theory and I came across the five-form flux defined in eq. 2.9.
Now, if one calculates the Ricci tensor for the given ansatz (eq. 2.6) and compare it with the action 2.1, one should get eq. 2.45 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6726). My question is how to get from 2.45 to 2.46? In particular I am able to reproduce all the contributions apart from the five-form one.
My understanding of five-form's components is the following: $$F_{a \mu\nu\rho\sigma} = \dfrac{1}{4!}(\partial_a\alpha)\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} $$ and $$F_{abcde} = \dfrac{1}{4!5!}(\partial_m\alpha)\sqrt{G}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\epsilon^{m\mu\nu\rho\sigma}_{abcde} .$$ Now, my problem is that I can't really obtain their 2.46, but more importantly I don't see how they have kept in eq. 2.45 the $F_{\mu abcd}$ contribution since it seems there is no such component given the ansatz used.
Did anyone already try this calculation before?